# Google Street View Style blurred zoom effect

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to recreate the zoomed blur motion effect you get when moving in Google Street View. I am trying to apply this effect to html images and videos. Like below. Can anybody help with any ideas about how I would go about this?

[image]

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
img {
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

for a blurred picture. Other styles [can be found here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_effects.asp)